# Is Flink's Match_Recognize function suitable for capturing this type of pattern?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-cep, match-recognize

I'm trying to catch events in pattern described below:

- Start event = SalePackageA event (Customer A purchasing PackageA)
- 2-nd event = PackageUsage event (Customer A uses PackageA)
- 3-rd event = PackageUsage event (Customer A uses PackageA)
- 4-th event = PackageUsage event (Customer A uses PackageA)
- ...
- N-th event = PackageUsage event (Customer A uses PackageA)
- Stop event = SalePackageA event (Customer A buys PackageA again)

Ie: customer purchased some data package with 2048mb balance, then customer using it - I receive used bytes in every PackageUsage event.

So, match_recognize should shout on every PackageUsage event with some aggregation logic:

```
( SalePackageA.Initial_Balance_Bytes - sum(present_event__PackageUsage.usage_bytes + sum(all_previous__PackageUsages.usage_bytes)) ) as Remaining_Balance
```

And when the same Customer purchases the same Package, this "flow" should be interrupted and a new "flow" will start over.

Is Flink's CEP suitable for described case? Any ideas/suggestions how to implement this using CEP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH_RECOGNIZE and CEP aren't a good match for your requirements (because you need to report the remaining balance after every usage event).

My suggestion is to implement this with a keyed process function.